# if then statement javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I tried to do an "if/then" statement in javascript but the "then" command is being ignored. Any ideas on why?

Specifically I want the form to be validated that the two text boxes are not blank and once that is validated I want a DIV ID = section2 to appear.

```
function checkanswers() {
    var fdet = document.wastheform;

    if (fdet.question_type[0].checked) {
        var elements = new Array("name","address");
        var elements_name = new Array("name", "address");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if ($("#" + elements[i]).val() == "") {
                err = "Please enter " + elements_name[i] + "";
                alert(err);
                return false;
            }
        }
        $("#section2").show();
    }
```

Comment: You have two `if` here. Which one doesn't seem to work ? And how did you chek it ?

Comment: Aren't you confusing names and ids ?

Comment: set a break point on the if statements and then use "add watch" to evaluate the different parts of the expression inside the if statement to determine why the left side doesn't equal the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your "then" is the showing of the div.  In which case I would do something like this:

```
function checkanswers() {
    var fdet = document.wastheform;

    if (fdet.question_type[0].checked) {
        if(withoutValue("#name")) {
            alert("Please enter name")
        }
        else if(withoutValue("#address")) {
            alert("Please enter address")
        } else {
            $("#section2").show();
        }

    }
}

function withoutValue(selector) {
    return $(selector).val() === "";
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies that you want an if/then behavior (in Javascript, this is more properly referred to as an if/else statement), but the way you structured your code, there is no "then". Here is how the if statement should work:

```
if ( condition )
{
    // do something if the condition is true
}
else
{
    // do something if the condition is false
}
```

Comment: This look like if/then-else/then :)

Comment: Well, given that Javascript doesn't have a 'then' statement, I was assuming what OP meant was 'if/else', and answered accordingly. But it's certainly possible I misunderstood.